# Timestamp time window issues when executing optimization request in Google Route Optimization

Tags: python, datetime, google-cloud-platform, optimization, timestamp

I'm executing some optimization request in Google Maps Platform Route Optimization and I'm getting the following code error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 INVALID_REQUEST: Validation caught 1 
error(s). Here is the first one: outside global time window (offending value(s): [2025- 
01-19T04:00:00-08:00, 2025-01-20T06:00:00-08:00])
```

Here is my model:

```
class TimeWindow(BaseModel):
    startTime: datetime
    endTime: datetime

class Delivery(BaseModel):
    arrivalLocation: Location
    duration: str
    timeWindows: List[TimeWindow] = []

class Shipment(BaseModel):
    shipmentID: str = None
    deliveries: Optional[List[Delivery]] = None
    pickUps: Optional[List[PickUp]] = None
    load: float
```

And here the DTOs I'm working with which I'm using to send the requests:

```
class TimeWindowDTO(BaseModel):
    startTime: str
    endTime: str

class DeliveryDTO(BaseModel):
    arrivalLocation: LocationDTO
    duration: str
    timeWindows: Optional[List[TimeWindowDTO]] = []


class PickupDTO(BaseModel):
    arrivalLocation: LocationDTO
    duration: str
    timeWindows: List[TimeWindowDTO] = []


class ShipmentDTO(BaseModel):
    shipmentID: str
    deliveries: List[DeliveryDTO]
    loadDemands: LoadDTO
    pickups: Optional[List[PickupDTO]] = []
```

The thing is that, first of all, I need to parse the model to DTO and here is the method to do so. I'm skipping the Shipment one since we are focused on the ones with date time:

```
def fromDeliveryToDeliveryDTO(delivery: Delivery) -> DeliveryDTO:
    location = LocationDTO(
        latitude=delivery.arrivalLocation.latitude,
        longitude=delivery.arrivalLocation.longitude
    )
    timeWindows = [TimeWindowDTO(startTime=timeWindow.startTime.strftime("%Y-%m- 
        %dT%H:%M:%S")+"Z", 
        endTime=timeWindow.endTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")+"Z") for timeWindow in 
        delivery.timeWindows]

        return DeliveryDTO(
            arrivalLocation=location,
            duration=delivery.duration,
            timeWindows=timeWindows
        )
```

Finally, here's the datetime part of the instance I'm using to test my request:

```
"timeWindows": [
                     {
                       "startTime": datetime(2025, 1, 19, 12, 0, 0, 
                           tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=1))),
                       "endTime": datetime(2025, 1, 19, 14, 0, 0, 
                           tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=1)))
                     }
                 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out there's a couple of variables that must be set prior to execute the optimization:  global_start_time and global_end_time. According to documentation:

```
global_start_time: "If unset, 00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970 (i.e. seconds: 
                    0, nanos: 0) is used as default."

global_end_time: "If unset, 00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1971 (i.e. seconds: 
                  31536000, nanos: 0) is used as default.
```

Since they were not set, my shipment time was outside the global time window. So the issue can be fixed just by doing:

```
global_start_time: str = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") + "Z"
global_end_time: str = (datetime.now()+timedelta(days=365)).strftime("%Y- 
                       %m-%dT%H:%M:%S") + "Z"
```